# Show Color Name in label

Tags: java, swing, colors, label, awt

Could anyone explain to me how can i show in a label, which color is being used for certain task.

Not to share whole code, here is what i basicly want to do.

```
  JColorChooser cc = new JColorChooser();
   Color c = cc.showDialog(rootPane, null, null);      
   L1.setText((String)(c.toString()));`
```

I have a button, that shows Color Chooser Dialog, i pick a color, and the only thing i want to is to print out color name to Label.
How ever this does not work, since i get "java.awt.Color[r=...g=...b=...]"

Maybe this is not possible, i am using default color chooser, should i create my own, and define color names alone ?

Comment: There are a lot of color in default color chooser. I don't think each color has a name.

Comment: As other replies have noted, there are not names for all of the 16,777,216 colors.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that there is some in built way to do it, however I tried to do something I hope it will help you, here you are:

```
public class ColorManager {
    public static void main(String [] args){
  SimpleColor yellow = new SimpleColor(22,32,45);
      ArrayList<SimpleColor> myColors = new ArrayList<SimpleColor>();
     for (SimpleColor color : myColors)
{


    if ((color.getR() == 12) && (color.getG() == 23) && (color.getB() == 23))
    {
        System.out.println("The colour is lets say yellow");
    }
}
}
}


public class SimpleColor {
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;

    public int getR() {
        return r;
    }

    public void setR(int r) {
        this.r = r;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(int b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int getG() {
        return g;
    }

    public void setG(int g) {
        this.g = g;
    }

    public SimpleColor(int r, int g, int b){
        this.r=r;
        this.b=b;
        this.g=g;
    }
}
```